# Resizing canvas to fit random shape size

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a certain random image shape which I want to fit the canvas to. The shape is saved in one layer with the canvas. I want the resultant saved JPG image without any background (white) only the shape appearing. can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: JPG files can not have transparent backgrounds. Unless your "shape" is rectangular, it will be *mandatory* to have a background color in the JPG format.

Comment: How to get then the desired result without saving it to JPG?

Comment: What do you need the image for? Print or web?

Answer (score 3):

Choose `Image > Trim` tick either the `Transparent Pixels` or the `Top left Pixel Color` option depending upon which is appropriate and click `OK`. Save.

Be aware, you **can not** save a JPG with transparency and **all** images are rectangular. So unless your "shape" is rectangular, you will need to either use a background color for a JPG, or save as a format which *does* support transparency such as PNG.